# jquery .on() method - accessing the correct page element

Tags: jquery

I have this html in a page:

```
<div id="page-container">
    <a class="myLink" href="http://www.example.com/">
    <span></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

and this jquery:

```
$('body').on('click','#page-container a', function(e){

   alert(e.target);

}
```

and this CSS:

```
a span {
    display: block;
    height: 36px;
    width: 36px;
    background-color: #eee;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    padding: 2px;
}
```

and I need to access the href "http://www.example.com/" and wanted to use e.target. But that returns the span object.  I have also tried $(this).attr(href). How do I access the href with the .on() method ?

Example of anomaly:  http://jsfiddle.net/guRXt/1/

Comment: Works fine for me (letting alone the syntax error at the end). http://jsfiddle.net/guRXt/

Comment: -1 for the lack of [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), @ me when you update the question reproducing it and I'll remove the dv.

Comment: I'd suggest doing `$("#page-container").on('click', 'a', function(e) { ... }`

Comment: This question's a bit too ambiguous. You should work to tighten it up a little.

Comment: `$(this).attr(href)` will work. `e.target` on the other will refer to the element that *triggered* the event, not the one that *handles* it (`e.currentTarget` does though, it's the same as `this`).

Comment: See Yotam's answer. It's precise and was given using the question as is.  So I don't think I deserved the downvote because that Jfiddle code was not exactly what I posted here. I do think I should have added CSS to have the link (a css button) shown.

Comment: Question was revised to show the issue in action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`e.target` is the element that triggered the event; `this` is the element the event is bound to.  They are not always the same.  You clicked on the `<span>`, so that's the "target".  `this` will always be the `<a>`.

```
$('body').on('click','#page-container a', function(e){
    alert(this.href);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`e.currentTarget`](http://api.jquery.com/event.currentTarget/) instead of `e.target`. If you had multiple nodes inside the `<a>` tag, you would see which specific one was clicked with `e.target`, whereas `e.currentTarget` will tell you with which object the event was handled.

If you need the `href` property, use `$(e.currentTarget).attr("href")`.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$(function(){
    $('#page-container').on('click','a', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert($(this).attr('href'));
    })                    
});
```

check this [working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JC7Rx/). You will also have to use `e.preventDefault();` so the click will not automatically take you to the href.

Comment: This is not correct. My function needs to target all "a" elements in "#page-container".

Comment: then change the selector from `.myLink` to `a`. I've updated.